# Detecting browser launching via Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am wondering if it's possible to listen for default browser launching with a service/broadcast receiver? If it's possible how am I suppose to do that ? Which intent-filter am I suppose to register the broadcaster with ? The purpose for this is to launch a full screen webview advertisement (like a video or a picture) whenever the user launches the default browser. Any answers, suggestion or examples will be welcomed :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a user launches the browser using the [Intent.ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW).

If you want to get do something then you can register to this intent...

Comment: Intent.Action_view is generic intent. How do a service get know when browser is launched ?

Comment: @Sam, you cannot know if the browser is launched unless it is your browser code.